Algorithm for estimating distortion of uvs from mesh parametrization
I have a triangular mesh with uvs generated from either a parametrization algorithm or through planar, spherical, etc projection. I would like to estimate the distortion or stretch of the said uvs. What is a good algorithm to achieve this?
